# Score text is not increasing in Unity After Seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

I am following one of the Udemy tutorials where it shows how to increase score after each second.

I have exactly done whatever he showed and I checked the code 10 times and the codes are the same but the score is not increasing.

Here is my **GameManager.cs** code:

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;
    public GameObject PlatformSpawner;
    public bool gameStarted;

    public bool gameEnd;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Text scoreText;
    int score = 0;
    

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!gameStarted)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                GameStart();  
            }
        }
    }

    public void GameStart()
    {
        gameStarted = true;
        PlatformSpawner.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        gameStarted = false;
        gameEnd = true;
        PlatformSpawner.SetActive(false); 
    }


    IEnumerator UpdateScore()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            score += 1;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the photo of unity where I have added `scoreText` in `GameManager`

[image]

Comment: You forgot to start the `UpdateScore` coroutine in your `GameStart` method

Comment: ya correct this worked thanks man, but its strange that in video tutorial that guy have not added anything In start :/

Comment: This is a very basic debugging, your mistake is just cross-checking your code from the tutorial, you haven't looked at your code once and understood what you have written, or understand how the code works and if you did understand, the issue is not so difficult to find. The problem in the code is that a coroutine is not started anywhere. This is very easy to debug yet you have not done it. It's high time you start with the basics of c# script and learn step by step instead of just jumping into creating projects that do not help if you lag in understanding concepts included in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice , can your provide me a good guide where I can learn?